# Cannot create a directory to /home

Tags: directory, home-directory

Is it normal that I can't create directories in `/home` partition as a normal user?

Example:

```
user@pc:/home$ mkdir test

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Permission denied
```

Is that normal?

Comment: @ignis Please add your comment as an answer, so that mecropa can accept it, and question is marked as closed.

Comment: @bkd.online Ok, done

Comment: Mind that if you do this and in the future you feel the need to create a user "test"  you might run into trouble.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a directory under `/home`? If you're trying to create a new user with a home directory, there are better ways to do this. I do not recommend creating a directory under `/home` for any other purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's expected, because your home is `/home/user`. `/home` is just the container for the home folders.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to create a directory under the `/home` folder, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
cd /home

sudo mkdir <name>
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for that but the problem is that the owner of the directory is still root.
the solution for now is
    chown -R username directory

Comment: @mecropa: `chown -R` is evil, just saying... be careful with that command. It can brick your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change the ownership of the created folder of a normal user won't be able to access it.
    sudo chown user:group newFolder